# POSTGRES (psql) - getting ERROR: must be owner of database, but I am doing it with the owner of the database

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, docker, psql

I have a script which deploys a web app to production. Currently, I am trying to implement a script in the begining which will "empty" the test database, before the database migrations are applied on it. This will be done to prevent "invalid/dirty database" problems, as everything will be newly created before attempting the migrations. Just a note, this runs in a `centOS` Docker container.

Anyways, this is what I tried to do:

```
    psql -U MYUSER \
    -h ${postgres_host} -c "DROP DATABASE my_test_database;"

    psql -U MYUSER \
    -h ${postgres_host} -c "CREATE DATABASE my_test_database;"

    psql -U MYUSER -h ${postgres_host} -d \
    my_test_database -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA 
    public;"
```

Running the script gave me the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user MYUSER
```

Doing a little bit of research, I found out about peer authentication, and found a way around it (without having to edit the `pg_conf` file). The way was to pass the password as well.

So, for the three commands I did the following:

```
    PGPASSWORD=${postgres_password} psql -U MYUSERNAME
    -h ${postgres_host} -c "DROP DATABASE test_database;"

    PGPASSWORD=${postgres_password} psql -U MYUSERNAME
    -h ${postgres_host} -c "CREATE DATABASE test_database;"

    PGPASSWORD=${postgres_password} psql -U MYUSERNAME -h ${postgres_host} -d \
    test_database -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA 
    public;"
```

The parameters I pass are defined earlier in the script. But now, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  must be owner of database test_database
```

However, the user I specify is THE owner. Can anyone point me toward the right way to do it or give me advice? If you need more info, I will be happy to oblige. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Had you verified the owner with this query? Select r.rolname
From pg_database d
Join pg_roles r on r.oid = d.datdba
Where datname = 'test_database'; or how?

Comment: Is in the log the same user that is getting the error?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, as specifying a password does not bypass peer authentication in the first place.  You are probably not connecting to the server you think you are.